# Backbone not making a put request with save() after save

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, backbone-views

I am experiencing a really interesting problem with backbone, I have a function like this in one of my views:

```
addpeople :function(){
        var authArray = _.clone(this.model.get("authorizedUsers"));
        var values = $(".add-input").val().split(",");
        values.forEach(function(value) {
            authArray.push(value);
        });
        this.model.set("authorizedUsers" , authArray);
        this.model.save();

    },
```

this function gets called when a button is clicked. This version of the function triggers a `change` event because I am cloning my array, but for some reason `this.model.save()`never gets called, aka the server never receives a PUT request. When I refresh the page I go back to the old state of the model..

However if I dont clone the array and change the function to, this:

```
addpeople :function(){
        var authArray = this.model.get("authorizedUsers");
        var values = $(".add-input").val().split(",");
        values.forEach(function(value) {
            authArray.push(value);
        });
        this.model.set("authorizedUsers" , authArray);
        this.model.save();

    },
```

This time the PUT request is sent successfully, but the page is not re-rendered because a change event is not triggered. When I refresh the page I can see the updated model..

I know that I can manually trigger a change event in the second example but I am more curious about why my `this.model.save()` is not called in the first example..

To help you understand the problem more my model looks something like:

```
var PostModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot : '/tweet',
    idAttribute: '_id',
    defaults:{
        name: '',
        comments: [],
        tags: [],
        authorizedUsers: [],
        postedBy : '',
        dateCreated: ''
    },


});
```

and my node.js update function looks like:

```
exports.updateTweet =  function(req,res){
  console.log("Getting called ! ")
  var update = req.body;
  var id = req.url.split("/")[2];

  Post.update({ _id: id }, { $set: { authorizedUsers: req.body.authorizedUsers }}, function (err, post) {
      if (err) return handleError(err);
  });
  res.end();

};
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason why `change` didn't trigger for your second example is because it is the same object and `Backbone` ignore it. Hence no `change` event triggered.

As for why the first one failed; do you have validator for your model? May be something that validating for empty string perhaps? `val()` can return an empty string and `split()` on empty string will return `[""]`

Also, your defaults should be a function otherwise all your model would have the same instance of `comments`, `tags` and `authorizedUsers`

From Backbone doc.

> *Remember that in JavaScript, objects are passed by reference, so if you include an object as a default value, it will be shared among all instances. Instead, define defaults as a function.*

Arrays are object too.

```
var PostModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot : '/tweet',
    idAttribute: '_id',
    defaults: function(){
      return {
          name: '',
          comments: [],
          tags: [],
          authorizedUsers: [],
          postedBy : '',
          dateCreated: ''
      }
  }
});
```

Lastly, `array.forEach()` is not available on IE8 and older.

Comment: can you explain more why `defaults` should be a function? how come all models use the same instance of array attribute?

Comment: thanks for your answer but I dont have a validate function in my model and as far as I know set() doesnt have an error callback.. How should go about debugging this?

Comment: hmm… did you override `Backbone.sync`? Did `request` triggered? Was there a call back to the server but not as `PUT` or there  was not call at all?

Comment: for some reason backbone is having a problem to save()