# Backbone "has no method 'call'" error

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have view like this:

```
var PostView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template(postTemplate),

    events: {
        'click .reply': 'addComment',
        'keypress textarea': 'addcommentOnEnter'
    },

    initialize: function(){
        _.bindAll(this, "render", "addcomment" , "addcommentOnEnter");
        this.model.bind('change', this.render);
    },

    addcomment : function(){
        this.model.comment($(".post-area").val());  
    },

    addcommentOnEnter : function(e){
        if (e.keyCode != 13) return;
        this.model.comment($(".post-area").val());
    },

    render: function(){
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    }
});
```

and whenever I click on `.reply` or press enter, meaning whenever `addcomment` or `addcommentOnEnter` is called I get and error on my console like this:

[image]

I have no idea what that means, but it doesnt seem to break anything in the application

```
var PostModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: '/tweet',
    idAttribute: '_id',
    defaults: {
        name: '',
        firstRemark: '',
        pictureUrl: '',
        postListing: '',
        comments: [],
        votes: 0,
        twitterHandle: '',
        votetype: 0,
        tags: [],
        authorizedUsers: [],
        postedBy: '',
        dateCreated: '',
        authorized: 0,
        change: ''
    },

    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, 'comment');
    },

    comment: function(comment, sender) {
        var commentsArray = this.get('comments');
        commentsArray.push({
            body: comment,
            by: window.user.displayName,
            profilePic: window.user.profilePic
        });
        this.set("comments", commentsArray);
        this.save();
        this.trigger('change');
    }
});
```

edit:
I am also having this issue [Backbone Navigation Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18137699/backbone-navigation-error) so they can be connected issues

Comment: It's likely miss-capitalization of your functions:  `"addcomment" , "addcommentOnEnter"`   Your object members both start with addC (capital C)

Comment: no sorry, my bad I capitalized it here to make it more readable.. just edited my question

Comment: It would likely help to post your model code as well since `Backbone.Model.extend.comment` is in the output.

Comment: done, I also added the backbone.js to my project instead of backbone.min.js and changes the screenshot

Comment: I am also having this issue Backbone Navigation Error so they can be connected issues

Comment: Guessing… Do you need to return `this` at the end of `render`?  I know [by convention it is preferred](http://backbonejs.org/#View-render).

Comment: The error means that you've bound an event handler that isn't a function, any chance of seeing a demo on jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com so that we can watch the bug happen? And two other things: you should be using a function if your `defaults` have mutable elements (such as objects or arrays) and you [can't `get`/`set` arrays like that](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11661380/479863) without problems (that's why you find yourself having to manually trigger that `'change'` event).

Comment: @muistooshort jsfiddle is on its way.. but when I clone my array and then set the new value, I am having problems with the save() function http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18117349/backbone-not-making-a-put-request-with-save-after-save/18122531#comment26562502_18122531

Answer (score 0):

I found it ! In one of my other views I had `this.model.bind('change', this.render());` instead of `this.model.bind('change', this.render)` ah so subtle,